# How to add items from database to listview?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I usually use this code to add item from datebase to list view:

```
public class ViewEvents extends Activity {

    DBAdapter DB=new DBAdapter(this);

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewevents);

        final ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.MyList);

          final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
          final ArrayAdapter<String>  aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);

           DB.open();
         Cursor c=DB.select();
          c.moveToFirst();
          Integer n=new Integer(c.getCount());

        for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
        {
             todoItems.add(0, c.getString(0));
             c.moveToNext();
        }

            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            myListView.setAdapter(aa);
enter code here
```

but, in my project I added image to listview as here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:drawablePadding="0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_remove" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/logo"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="25px" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

That causes problem in arrayadapter, I can't catch listview as usuall:

```
ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.MyList);
```

any advice please

the new code:

```
public class RemoveEvent extends ListActivity {

    DBAdapter DB=new DBAdapter(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
         final ArrayAdapter<String>  aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);


         DB.open();
         Cursor c=DB.select();
          c.moveToFirst();
          Integer n=new Integer(c.getCount());
        for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
        {
             todoItems.add(0, c.getString(0));
             c.moveToNext();
        }


           // todoItems.add(0, c.getString(0));
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            setListAdapter(new RemoveArrayAdapter(this, .......));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        //get selected items
        String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

removearrayadapter code:

```
public class RemoveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public RemoveArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.removeevent, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.removeevent, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        textView.setText(values[position]);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your question? What is problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That causes problem in arrayadapter, I can't catch listview as usuall:

What exactly does this means? What is the exception you get(if any)?

Some issues:

If you use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` then what is with the xml layout you posted?
If you plan to use that layout file then use this constructor of `ArrayAdapter`:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String>  aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.Name_of_layout_you_posted, R.id.label, todoItems);
```

Also if you plan to pass the `Context`:

```
 DBAdapter DB=new DBAdapter(this);
```

Then you should initialize the *db* in the `onCreate` method:

```
DBAdapter DB;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewevents);
    DB = new DBAdapter(this);
    //... rest of the code
```

Also, you should try to use a `Cursor` based adapter so you don't have to parse the cursor in a list.

**Edit :**
Modify your `RemoveArrayAdapter` to accept the ArrayList that you fill with data from the `Cursor`:

```
    public class RemoveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<String> values;

        public RemoveArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
            super(context, R.layout.removeevent, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.removeevent, parent, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
            textView.setText(values.get(position));
            // I'm guessing you want to modify the Logo?!? if yes pass another ArrayList to this adapter
           //contaning the info to set the ImageView  
            return rowView;
        }

}
```

And in the `RemoveActivity`:

```
for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++) {
    todoItems.add(c.getString(0));
    c.moveToNext();
}
setListAdapter(new RemoveArrayAdapter(this, todoItems));
```

Comment: thank you at first ..
I didn't create listview in xml, but I inherited it in java file, so I can't call it by ID, I can't set adapter for it
myListView.setAdapter(aa)

Comment: @SWE How exactly you inherited in java file? Your activity doesn't extends `Activity` and you can't inherit a `ListView` from that. Maybe you wanted `ViewEvents` to extend `ListActivity`(even in this case you must have a `ListView` with the id `"@android:id/list"`)?

Comment: @SWE ?!? So it's ok now or...?

Comment: I am so sory, I extend from listactivity,and I put in the post what I did on normal work, this is the extending code:
public class RemoveEvent extends ListActivity {

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayAdapter<String>  aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);

Comment: DB.open();
         Cursor c=DB.select();
          c.moveToFirst();
          Integer n=new Integer(c.getCount());
       for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
       {
         todoItems.add(0, c.getString(0));
         c.moveToNext();
       }
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            myListView.setAdapter(aa);
  

 }

really I am sory, for mistakes

Comment: @SWE I've seen the code, but do you still have problems(if yes do you have exception in the logcat)?

Comment: I still have problem, and i can't run the code
I changed in code, but I did't know what parameters of setlistadapter(.....)
this the new code

public class RemoveEvent extends ListActivity {
 DBAdapter DB=new DBAdapter(this);
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
      final ArrayAdapter<String>  aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);

Comment: DB.open();
         Cursor c=DB.select();
          c.moveToFirst();
          Integer n=new Integer(c.getCount());
       for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
       {
         todoItems.add(0, c.getString(0));
         c.moveToNext();
       }
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            setListAdapter(new RemoveArrayAdapter(this, .......));

 }

Comment: @SWE Edit your question and post there the code with proper formatting(and also add the code for `RemoveArrayAdapter`).

Comment: it is working, thank you very much :)
please can you explain what did you do

Comment: @SWE I've just replaced the *values* array(from `RemoveArrayAdapter`) with an `ArrayList` and then supplied the todoItems `ArrayList` in the `onCreate` method to populate the `ListView`. Also you should use the method `add(String)` when adding values from the cursor to `todoItems`.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do this its a lot easier

```
ListView lv = (ListView)d.findViewById(R.id.dialog_list);
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(BowlersDB.CONTENT_URI,new String[] {BowlersDB.ID,BowlersDB.NAME},null,null,BowlersDB.NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
            if(c.moveToFirst() && c != null){
                SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.names_listview,c
                        ,new String[] {BowlersDB.NAME},new int[] {R.id.bListTextView});
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

basically just pass the cursor into the simple cursor adapter and it will populate the list from your layouts, no need to make a listadapter when you already have the information

EDIT: custom adapter example

```
public class ImageAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
Context context;

public ImageAdapter(Context context,int textViewResourceId,Cursor c,String[] from,int[] to){
    super(context,textViewResourceId,c,from,to);

    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void setViewText(TextView tv,String text){
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(BowlersDB.CONTENT_URI,new String[] {BowlersDB.ID,BowlersDB.NAME}
    ,BowlersDB.ID+"="+text,null,null);
    if(c.moveToFirst() && c != null){
        tv.setText(c.getString(1));
    }
    c.close();
}
@Override
public void setViewImage(ImageView iv,String text){
    if(text.equals("1")){
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.rate_star_small_on_holo_light);
    }
}

}
```

these 2 parts of code are from two different sections of my program so please dont think they go together

Comment: thank you, I do near of this for normal listview
but now I added a image for list
as the XML code in my post
In my java file I extended from listactivity, so I cant catach the list to add item for it :(

Comment: what do you mean? are you saying because you have an image in your layout you think you cant do this? just create a custom adapter and override the `setImageView`. I updated my answer to show you what i mean

Answer (score 0):

you can use my code

```
        Cursor cursor = myDBClass.returnResult();

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList();
     for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !(cursor.isAfterLast()); cursor.moveToNext())
      {
       result.add( cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDBClass.BI_Attr2)));
      }
    String[] Values= new String[result.size()];

    for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++)
    {
        Values[i]=result.get(i);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, android.R.id.text1, Values);
    // set this adapter as your ListActivity's adapter
    ListView LV=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.LVV);
    LV.setAdapter(adapter);
    LV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
        //Do whatever you want onClick of item of ListView
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you, I do near of this for normal listview
but now I added a image for list
as the XML code in my post
In my java file I extended from listactivity, so I cant catach the list to add item for it :(